# How can I send a multipart request with a file and a JSON payload?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to create a request to an endpoint that takes a zip file and a JSON body that should be a list of objects.

I can't seem to find a solution for sending a successful request. When I try to execute the request from Swagger-UI, I get a 415 error code.

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/fillPdfZip", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
        
 public ResponseEntity<byte[]> fillPdfTemplateAndCompress(
    @RequestPart("templateZip") MultipartFile templateZip,
    @RequestPart("pdfInfoDtoList") List<PdfInfoDto> pdfInfoDtoList)
```

Can someone help me understand how to submit a valid request to this service?